# How to cite different authors with the same last name with Bibtex

Tags: r-markdown, bibtex, bibliography

I am using rmarkdown with bibtex citation package, but don't know how to handle the citation of different authors with the same last name. I found the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287970/how-to-cite-two-different-authors-with-the-same-surname-in-bibtex, but this does not work with rmarkdown. Any help would be appreciated.

```
---
title: "Paper"  
thanks: 
author: |
  | \normalfont myself
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    citation_package: natbib
    fig_caption: true
    fig_height: 4.5
    fig_width: 8
link-citations: yes
toc: false
bibliography: /Users/jj/Documents/ch3/references02.bib
biblio-style: apalike    
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.2
subparagraph: true
number_sections: true
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \usepackage{bbm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{indentfirst}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{booktabs, colortbl, xcolor}
- \usepackage{babel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
- \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
- \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
- \newtheorem{algorithem}{Algorithm}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
- \newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
- \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
- \UseRawInputEncoding
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = blue,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{flafter}
- \floatstyle{plaintop}
- \restylefloat{table}
- \setlength{\parindent}{2.5em}
- \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes} 
- \usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
- \creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{figure}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{table}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{section}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{accents}
- \newcommand*{\dt}[1]{%
- \accentset{\mbox{\large\bfseries .}}{#1}}
- \DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
- \usepackage{cleveref}

---
```

`references02.bib` file is the following:

```
@incollection{chang2003,
author="Chang, Ha-Joon",
editor="Ha-Joon Chang",
title="Trade and Industrial Policy Issues",
bookTitle="Rethinking Development Economics",
year="2003",
publisher="Anthem Press",
pages="257-276"
}

@book{sjchang2003, 
place={Cambridge}, 
title={Financial Crisis and Transformation of Korean Business Groups: The Rise and Fall of Chaebols}, 
DOI={10.1017/CBO9780511510861}, 
publisher={Cambridge University Press}, 
author={Chang, Sea-Jin}, 
year={2003}
}
```

The text would be:
`\cite{chang2003}` and `\cite{sjchang2003}` said different things, blah blah...